# Python test if client exist

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I am new to python and working on trying to make a script which checks if a specified host as for example sensu-client exist. I use a deployment software called NSO and run it by: `nso status` and it shows me this information:

```
nagios-client host nagios-client down
test host test down
```

Is there any possibility to make a script to check if for example nagios-Client exist with a script ?

In shell I do it by:

```
nso status | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you give more details about what problem you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would suggest using subprocess' check_output function. The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). check_output can return, as a string the shell output of a command. So you would have something like this:

```
import subprocess
foo=subprocess.check_output(['nso', 'status', '|', 'awk', '\'{ print $1 }\''], shell=True) 
#Thanks bereal for shell=True
print foo
```

Of course, if your only targeting linux, you could use the much easier [sh module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh). It allows you to import programs as if they were libraries.

Comment: You'll need to add `shell=True` for this pipe to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use subprocess to run this command and parse the output

```
import subprocess
command = ['nso', 'status', '|', 'awk', '\'{ print $1 }\'']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: This won't produce the desired result, you changed from `command` to `first` in your code, so you should probably pick one, otherwise it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run `awk`, since you're already in Python:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['nso', 'status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# get stdout as a EOL-separated string, ignore stderr for now
out, _ = proc.communicate()  

# parse the output, line.split()[0] is awk's $1
items = [line.split()[0] for line in out.split('\n')]
```